# R Markdownd: ! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands

Tags: r, pdf, error-handling, latex, markdown

I am trying to knit a pdf in Rmarkdown, but I receive the same error over and over again:
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

I already different approaches like deleting some rows, putting \begin{document} in different places or changing the order of loading packages.

This is my code:

```
---
title: "Feedback"
author: "Me"
date: "09 02 2021"
toc: true
toc_depth: 2
toc-title: "Verzeichnis"
fig.caption: "Tabelle"
smooth_scroll: false
header-includes: 
  \documentclass{article}
  \PassOptionsToPackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
  \usepackage{tikz}
mainfont: SourceSansPro
output: pdf_document
---
\begin{document}


\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} 
\thispagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width = 500pt]{"/Users/lisak/One Drive/OneDrive/Dokumente/Masterarbeit/Erhebung/Anschreiben/alt/banner.png"}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 


{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
.onLoad <- function(libname = find.package("kableExtra"), pkgname = "kableExtra") {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    load_packages <- getOption("kableExtra.latex.load_packages", default = TRUE)
    if (load_packages) {
      usepackage_latex("booktabs")
      usepackage_latex("longtable")
      usepackage_latex("array")
      usepackage_latex("multirow")
      usepackage_latex("wrapfig")
      usepackage_latex("float")
      usepackage_latex("colortbl")
      usepackage_latex("pdflscape")
      usepackage_latex("tabu")
      usepackage_latex("threeparttable")
      usepackage_latex("threeparttablex")
      usepackage_latex("ulem", "normalem")
      usepackage_latex("makecell")
      usepackage_latex("xcolor")   
      
    }
  }
  auto_format <- getOption("kableExtra.auto_format", default = TRUE)
  if (auto_format) auto_set_format()
  if (!is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) &&
      rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% c(
        "ioslides_presentation", "slidy_presentation",
        "gitbook", "bookdown::gitbook", "radix_article", "radix::radix_article",
        "distill_article", "distill::distill_article"
      )) {
    options(kableExtra.html.bsTable = TRUE)
  }
  if (!is.null(knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")) &&
      knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") %in% c("epub3", "epub")) {
    options(kableExtra.knit_print.dependency = FALSE)
  }
}

stuff....

\end{document}
```

Comment: Rmarkdown will automatically insert stuff like `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` when converting the rmarkdown document into a tex document.

Comment: If I leave these commands out, I get the error: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rmarkdown will automatically insert stuff like `\documentclass{article}` and `\begin{document}` when converting the rmarkdown document into a tex document. You must not insert it a second time
- `\PassOptionsToPackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` must be used before the documentclass. As rmarkdown takes away your ability to insert the document class yourself, you can't use this
- rmarkdown has trouble to correctly parse the square brackets of optional arguments. As a workaround, you can hide these commands in a separate .tex file
- the syntax of your r chunk is wrong. You must surround it with backticks

---

````
---
title: "Feedback"
author: "Me"
date: "09 02 2021"
toc: true
toc_depth: 2
toc-title: "Verzeichnis"
fig.caption: "Tabelle"
smooth_scroll: false
mainfont: SourceSansPro
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---


```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
.onLoad <- function(libname = find.package("kableExtra"), pkgname = "kableExtra") {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    load_packages <- getOption("kableExtra.latex.load_packages", default = TRUE)
    if (load_packages) {
      usepackage_latex("booktabs")
      usepackage_latex("longtable")
      usepackage_latex("array")
      usepackage_latex("multirow")
      usepackage_latex("wrapfig")
      usepackage_latex("float")
      usepackage_latex("colortbl")
      usepackage_latex("pdflscape")
      usepackage_latex("tabu")
      usepackage_latex("threeparttable")
      usepackage_latex("threeparttablex")
      usepackage_latex("ulem", "normalem")
      usepackage_latex("makecell")
      usepackage_latex("xcolor")   
      
    }
  }
  auto_format <- getOption("kableExtra.auto_format", default = TRUE)
  if (auto_format) auto_set_format()
  if (!is.null(rmarkdown::metadata$output) &&
      rmarkdown::metadata$output %in% c(
        "ioslides_presentation", "slidy_presentation",
        "gitbook", "bookdown::gitbook", "radix_article", "radix::radix_article",
        "distill_article", "distill::distill_article"
      )) {
    options(kableExtra.html.bsTable = TRUE)
  }
  if (!is.null(knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")) &&
      knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") %in% c("epub3", "epub")) {
    options(kableExtra.knit_print.dependency = FALSE)
  }
}
```

stuff....
````

and `preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} 
\thispagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width = 500pt]{example-image}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! But I am a bit confused:
What happend to `\PassOptionsToPackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` ? I can't find it in your answer and where do I have to put the code so that it is before the documentclass? And how do I exactly create this .tex file? Like where and how do I type that in. Sorry, I have made use of .tex file before

Comment: @psycho95 As I said, you can't use this with rmarkdown. If you actually need these options, you could pass them via a `classoption` to all packages. I'm not aware of any other package using these keywords, so this should not cause too many problems, but one can't rule this out

Comment: For the .tex file you can use whatever texteditor you like, even rstudio should be able to create new files

Comment: Okay thank you, I got this. But where do I save the tex document? I put it in the same place I am loading my dataset from, but I get `File preamble.tex not found in resource path`

Comment: @psycho95 Try same place as your .rmd file

Comment: Thanks! But I am still receiving `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` ...

Comment: @psycho95 On rstudio cloud it compiles without error https://rstudio.cloud/project/2262233